# nixos-shell in nixos vm does not seem to be recognizing store paths that exist?

Tags: nix, nixos

I'm using https://github.com/Mic92/nixos-shell to build/run a VM.

Within this VM, I try run `nixos-shell` which initially failed with an error however after adding:

```
{...}: {
  nix.nixPath = [
    "nixpkgs=${pkgs.path}"
  ];
}
```

It now works, however it seems to be downloading  dependencies that should already exist in the host, when trying to invoke something via `nix-shell`.

```
nix-shell -p vim                                                                                       /bambie
these paths will be fetched (7.00 MiB download, 33.13 MiB unpacked):
  /nix/store/1cbk7i6dg26cygss2b6w8xq4dnj50z31-vim-8.2.1522
copying path '/nix/store/1cbk7i6dg26cygss2b6w8xq4dnj50z31-vim-8.2.1522' from 'https://cache.nixos.org'...
^Cerror: interrupted by the user
```

Why is this occurring? When the path (`/nix/store/1cbk7i6dg26cygss2b6w8xq4dnj50z31-vim-8.2.1522`) is present on the VM (I say this because it's present when I do `ls /nix/store/1cbk7i6dg26cygss2b6w8xq4dnj50z31-vim-8.2.1522`)?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but I believe this explains why this behavior is occurring:

> The issue here is that when you’re using Nix inside the VM, the store
> paths from the host aren’t registered in Nix’s SQLite database. On the
> other hand however all the store paths from the host machine should be
> available within the VM (except of course if the VM is running inside
> a Nix build process).

https://discourse.nixos.org/t/how-to-build-a-nixos-vm-with-nix-in-which-nixos-rebuild-is-a-no-op/7937/2